# Discoverable grails web service for multiple platform apps

Tags: web-services, grails

I have the following:
 - Grails Web Application
 - Domain classes bunded as a plugin that is included in web app.
 - Android and iphone apps that use the restful urls of the web app to make server calls (json requests/responses).

Here is the problem:
Both the mobile app have no way of knowing what calls they can make (What are valid attributes, etc). Developers simply have to look at the web apps code to figure out the url to hit and the domain models attributes to set in the request.

I was wondering was there some grails plugin that allows you to define your domain models via xml (Or some other format) and then generate their grrovy classes (stub classes) that can be packaged up as a jar. This jar could then be included in the android app as a dependency.

Likewise maybe the xml could also be used to generate classes for the iphone app (There is more than likely no plugin for this I suspect).

It would be great to get some thought's on this approach. Is it a good idea? Is there a better way to approach it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could define your JSON interface with Java DTOs. Then you can include those in your Android app. I've just made an app like that. But next time I don't think I'll bother with the DTOs -  more hassle than benefit, I think.

Best,
Anders